# how do I manipulate mySQL database in mySQLworkbench through a PHP script using PDO class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysql-workbench

I have a registered domain name and have web hosting. I successfully connected to the database server through mySQLworkbench by using the server's IP address, port, my username, and password. I can create, read, update and delete entries from my database directly through workbench. But my question is how do I use PHP script to manipulate a database that is stored within workbench? Also, I was wondering what SSH configuration is used for? If you haven't guessed, I'm a beginner at this and if you could point me to the right direction, that would be great!

Comment: PHP won't run in workbench. PHP generally runs on the web server. You are issuing SQL commands to the database server through workbench. Perhaps do some more reading about [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29).

Comment: MySQL workbench *does not store the databases*. The databases are stored (managed) by MySQL server; the Workbench is simply a data viewer and admin tool

Answer (score 1):

you can not store database inside mysqlworkbench. As the name says workbench is a tool to manage database, in this case, mysql, it is a workbench not a RDBMS. You can use workbench to create models, perform queries and admin tasks. But the database it self is mysql.

Said that, to access the database through php pdo use this:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Only idiots downvote without comments!

Answer (score 1):

You have few misconception:

- Your database is stored in `mysql` server and not `Workbench`
- `Workbench` is just a client program to connect remotely to your `mysql` server.
- `SSH` ? for what, this has nothing to do with [`SSH`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell).
- To talk to your database, you need to setup drivers along with `PHP`

---

Take a look at the following drivers:

- [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)
- [**mysqli**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

There are many more, but `PDO` is the preferred one, whatever you use make sure you use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).